# I18n::InvalidPluralizationData how to track error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I've seen similar posts about this but I still can't figure out where my error is coming from

My I18n fails every time it needs to pluralize something in french. Everytime it's a similar error with :count

Example : `translation data {:one=>"est trop court (au moins un caractère)", :other=>"est trop court (au moins %{count} caractères)"} can not be used with :count => 2`

Other errors occur with translation like these ones (always when trying to pluralize)

```
datetime:
  distance_in_words:
    x_days:
      one:   "1 jour"
      other: "%{count} jours"
```

I have the /locale/fr.yml [from this github](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/fr.yml).

A part of my Trace

```
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/pluralization.rb:35:in `pluralize'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:40:in `translate'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n.rb:158:in `block in translate'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n.rb:154:in `catch'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n.rb:154:in `translate'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:118:in `block in resolve'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:115:in `catch'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:115:in `resolve'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:102:in `block in default'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:101:in `each'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:101:in `default'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:34:in `translate'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n.rb:158:in `block in translate'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n.rb:154:in `catch'
i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n.rb:154:in `translate'
activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/errors.rb:435:in `generate_message'
activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/errors.rb:442:in `normalize_message'
activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/errors.rb:293:in `add'
activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/validations/length.rb:57:in `block in validate_each'
activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/validations/length.rb:45:in `each'
activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/validations/length.rb:45:in `validate_each'
mongoid (4.0.0) lib/mongoid/validatable/localizable.rb:25:in `validate_each'
activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/validator.rb:167:in `block in validate'
activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/validator.rb:164:in `each'
activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/validator.rb:164:in `validate'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `public_send'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:184:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:184:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
mongoid (4.0.0) lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
```

Everything is fine in English however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use key name as :many.

```
datetime:
  distance_in_words:
    x_days:
      one:   "1 jour"
      many: "%{count} jours"
```

As per my understanding lib/i18n/backend/pluralization.rb:35:in `pluralize'
this method call a proc which is defined in
"gems/numbers_and_words-0.10.0/lib/numbers_and_words/i18n/plurals"
based on diffrent locales .
If we look into fr.rb its key name we need to use.